# Retrieve the host keys from an azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

I am trying to script an environment using the Azure cli. I have created a few function apps and would like to add a host key or at least retrieve the default one that is created automatically. The azure cli has no support at all for this.

There seems to be an api (documentation for it seems to be sparse) on the function itself that allows me to get the keys, however you need a key to use it so.. no help there.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Key-management-API

Eg: https://example-functions.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/keys?code=somecodeyoualreadyknow

I have seen some other examples that use the webapps scm api to download the json file that contains the keys however I'm not sure how to authenticate with this API. I have a service principal (userid, password, tenantid) and I was hoping to not have to add another authentication scheme to my script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the steps.

1. Assuming you already have your Kudu deployment credentials. (it sounds like you already know how to do this. You can get it via an ARM call from your service principle, etc)
2. From kudu deployment creds, you can get a JWT that lets you call the Functions key API.
3. From the Functions API, you can get all your keys (including your master).

Here's a powershell script that demonstrates the exact calls to go from Kudu deployment creds to Function Master key:

```
# You need to start with these:
$site = "YourSiteName"
$username='YourDeploymentUserName'
$password='YourDeploymentPassword'

# Now... 
$apiBaseUrl = "https://$($site).scm.azurewebsites.net/api"
$siteBaseUrl = "https://$($site).azurewebsites.net"

# For authenticating to Kudu
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))


# Call Kudu /api/functions/admin/token to get a JWT that can be used with the Functions Key API 
$jwt = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/functions/admin/token" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET

# Call Functions Key API to get the master key 
$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$siteBaseUrl/admin/host/systemkeys/_master" -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $jwt)} -Method GET

$masterKey = $x.value
```

Comment: Hi, I have the service principal credentials but as I understand it they are not the same. I do not know how to get "kudo" credentials with my service principal credentials.

Answer (score 9):

I was just able to make this work with the Azure CLI using this command:

```
az rest --method post --uri \
"/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$FUNCTION_APP_NAME/host/default/listKeys?api-version=2018-11-01" \
--query functionKeys.default --output tsv
```

I realize this is a couple years late on the answer, but it might help people who are searching now.

Comment: I was totally searching for this today. Been looking for hours trying to figure out how to do this in a 2019 way... you sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thanks!

Comment: There's also a slot specific endpoint [.../Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/slots/{slot}/host/default/listkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-host-keys-slot) which will come in handy because a swapping will swap the host keys.

Answer (score 6):

> I do not know how to get "kudu" credentials with my service principal credentials

If C# code is acceptable, we could use [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/) and [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) to do that easily. The following is the demo that how to get kudu credentials and run Key management API .I test it locally, it works correctly on my side.

```
 string clientId = "client id";
 string secret = "secret key";
 string tenant = "tenant id";
 var functionName ="functionName";
 var webFunctionAppName = "functionApp name";
 string resourceGroup = "resource group name";
 var credentials = new AzureCredentials(new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = secret}, tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
 var azure = Azure
          .Configure()
          .Authenticate(credentials)
          .WithDefaultSubscription();

 var webFunctionApp = azure.AppServices.FunctionApps.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroup, webFunctionAppName);
 var ftpUsername = webFunctionApp.GetPublishingProfile().FtpUsername;
 var username = ftpUsername.Split('\\').ToList()[1];
 var password = webFunctionApp.GetPublishingProfile().FtpPassword;
 var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
 var apiUrl = new Uri($"https://{webFunctionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api");
 var siteUrl = new Uri($"https://{webFunctionAppName}.azurewebsites.net");
 string JWT;
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {base64Auth}");

     var result = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/functions/admin/token").Result;
     JWT = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Trim('"'); //get  JWT for call funtion key
   }
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWT);
    var key = client.GetAsync($"{siteUrl}/admin/functions/{functionName}/keys").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to get the keys and don't need to automate the authentication process:

```powershell
Get-AzResource -Name RESOURCE-NAME | Invoke-AzResourceAction -Action host/default/listkeys -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both for your replies. Using your answer Mike S and rummaging around the csharp fluent source code (thanks Tom Sun) I ended up with this. Sure do need a lot of tokens! The credentials I start with are what you would get back from `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n $name --role contributor`

```
$credentials = (ConvertFrom-Json $env:AzureCliLogin)

$tenant = $credentials.tenant
$clientId = $credentials.appId
$clientSecret = $credentials.password
$subscriptionId = "<subscription id>"

$body = @{
    "grant_type"="client_credentials";
    "client_id"=$clientId;
    "client_secret"=$clientSecret;
    "resource"="https://management.azure.com/"
}

$authInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant/oauth2/token" -Body $body -Method Post -Headers @{"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} 

$publishData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$name/publishxml?api-version=2016-08-01" -Method Post -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $($authInfo.access_token)"}

$userName = $publishData.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
$password = $publishData.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD

$apiBaseUrl = "https://$name.scm.azurewebsites.net/api"
$siteBaseUrl = "https://$name.azurewebsites.net"

# For authenticating to Kudu
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))    

# Call Kudu /api/functions/admin/token to get a JWT that can be used with the Functions Key API 
$jwt = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/functions/admin/token" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method GET

# Call Functions Key API to get the master key 
$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$siteBaseUrl/admin/host/systemkeys/_master" -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $jwt)} -Method GET

$masterKey = $x.value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in bash, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/flacito/4bbbe2c8f02d65b0f14d7a3439879d4c) for a start

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of the Az Module.

Install:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Force
```

or

Update:

```
Update-Module -Name Az
```

Be sure and launch a new PowerShell window after running one of the above commands.

Then you can just run the following after you set up your resource group name and function name variables:

```
$azureFunction = Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $azureFunctionName
$keys = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId $($azureFunction.Id) -Action "host/default/listKeys" -Force
$defaultKey = $keys.functionKeys.default
```