# Retreive the host key from within my azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

To read an Application setting in Azure function I can do

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyVariable", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Is it possible to get a Host key in a similar way? I like to identify the caller of my azure function based on the key they are using but hate to have a copy of this key in Application settings

Comment: is it like a RSA key ?. you can store it in azure keyvault and then retrieve it in the function and use it.

Comment: i think he is talking about the key that is used to protect azure function (so the key you put in url to launch it) @Aravind

Comment: @4c74356b41 function keys have to be sent along with the http request always to access the function isn't it

Comment: @4c74356b41 yes that is correct.

Comment: yes, my understanding is - he is asking how to understand which key was used to call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/) and [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) to do that easily. 
The following is the demo that how to get kudu credentials and run Key management API .I test it locally, it works correctly on my side.

For more detail, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338239/retrieve-the-host-keys-from-an-azure-function-app) with C# code or use [powershell](http://bloggingoncloud.com/get-azure-function-app-master-key-host-key-by-api-end-point-programmatically/) to get it.

```
string clientId = "client id";
 string secret = "secret key";
 string tenant = "tenant id";
 var functionName ="functionName";
 var webFunctionAppName = "functionApp name";
 string resourceGroup = "resource group name";
 var credentials = new AzureCredentials(new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = secret}, tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
 var azure = Azure
          .Configure()
          .Authenticate(credentials)
          .WithDefaultSubscription();

 var webFunctionApp = azure.AppServices.FunctionApps.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroup, webFunctionAppName);
 var ftpUsername = webFunctionApp.GetPublishingProfile().FtpUsername;
 var username = ftpUsername.Split('\\').ToList()[1];
 var password = webFunctionApp.GetPublishingProfile().FtpPassword;
 var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
 var apiUrl = new Uri($"https://{webFunctionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api");
 var siteUrl = new Uri($"https://{webFunctionAppName}.azurewebsites.net");
 string JWT;
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {base64Auth}");

     var result = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/functions/admin/token").Result;
     JWT = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Trim('"'); //get  JWT for call funtion key
   }
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWT);
    var key = client.GetAsync($"{siteUrl}/admin/functions/{functionName}/keys").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  }
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: Did you read this update? I understand it as this solution will stop working since the keys will be moved to Blob Storage ?

Comment: Since update 2.0.12050 de keys are no longer stored as a storage file but in a blob-container. 
A (temporary?) solution is to restore the location of the secrets by changing App Setting **AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType** to **files**. 
see also https://aka.ms/funcsecrets