# Are function/host keys directly available inside an Azure Function written in Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

When writing an Azure Function in Python, I would *expect* to be able to access the host and function keys from the environment. Is this possible? All the examples I've seen do it by calling a `get` request, which seems like a lot of code to access something that I've set through the website.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51492408/retreive-the-host-key-from-within-my-azure-function) is very similar, but not language specific.

Comment: AFAIK To support programmatic key management, the host exposes a key management AP and API is the only way of getting function and host key. API keys are persisted, encrypted, on the file system under D:\home\data\Functions\secrets, in files matching the function name for function level keys, and a file named host.json for the host level keys.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to get the response of the Host API `admin/host/keys` of Azure Functions as below, so please refer to Azure Functions wiki page [`Key management API`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API)

[image]

Here is my sample code.

```
# App Credentials, to get it see the figures below
username = "<your username like `$xxxxx`>"
password = "<your password>"

functionapp_name = "<your function app name>"
api_url = f"https://{functionapp_name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api"
site_url = f"https://{functionapp_name}.azurewebsites.net"

import base64
import requests

auth_info = f"{username}:{password}"

base64_auth = base64.b64encode(str.encode(auth_info)).decode()
print(base64_auth)

jwt_resp = requests.get(f"{api_url}/functions/admin/token", headers={"Authorization": f"Basic {base64_auth}"})
jwt = jwt_resp.text.replace("\"", "", -1)
print(jwt)

keys_resp = requests.get(f"{site_url}/admin/host/keys", headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {jwt}"})
print(keys_resp.text)
```

It works and its result as below.

[image]

For getting the username and password of App Credentials, please see the figures below.

Fig 1. On Azure portal, open the `Platform features` tab of your Function App and click the `Deployment Center` link

[image]

Fig 2. Select the `FTP` option in the first step of `SOURCE CONTROL` and click the `Dashboard` button to copy the values of `Username` and `Password`, but just use the part of `Username` with `$` prefix as `username` variable in my script. Ofcouse, you also can use them in tab `User Credentials` tab.

[image]

Also, you can refer to my answer for the similar SO thread [Unable to access admin URL of Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843059/unable-to-access-admin-url-of-azure-functions/54861921#54861921) using PowerShell, and my figures below come from that.

---

**Update**: For using Azure Function for Python in container, please refer to the figure below to get the deployment credentials.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I'm writing a python function, and therefore by deployment is via the VS Code tools, which leads to it being containerised. Which means that under Code Deployment i only get Container settings, which is greyed out.
Does any of that change the way I should be doing this?