# Output newly created function app key using Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have a bicep template that creates a function app in a dedicated module. I would like out the function app key from the module. Anyone know how I can get the function key?

I can't find it in the list of properties:

[image]

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56854395/1658906. It's for ARM templates, but should apply in a similar way to Bicep templates.

Comment: Yep, the `listkeys` function should help. Which key are you trying to output ? host key ? a function key ?

Comment: host keys/default would be fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you would like to retrieve the default host key, you can use the `listkeys` function:

```bicep
param functionAppName string

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: functionAppName
}

resource functionAppHost 'Microsoft.Web/sites/host@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: 'default'
  parent: functionApp
}

// Default host key
output defaultHostKey string = functionAppHost.listKeys().functionKeys.default

// Master key
output masterKey string = functionAppHost.listKeys().masterKey

// Addtionally grab the system keys
output systemKeys object = functionAppHost.listKeys().systemKeys
```

Comment: Does not work for me (anymore), I get the error `No route registered for '/api/functions/MyFunctionName/host/default/listkeys?api-version=2016-08-01'`

Comment: @HeinrichUlbricht You need to deploy your code to the Function App, before `/api/functions/MyFunctionName` is created. The functions inside the Function App are created by the code. Therefore I recommend getting the host key using Azure CLI:
1. Deploy Function App
2. Deploy code
3. Get host key

Comment: The solution is great but a different approach needed if the function app is created in a module rather than directly in the "main" bicep template: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76463916/get-function-app-default-host-key-when-created-in-bicep-module

Comment: @Thomas is this still the official API and version to use in 2024 to get the function keys? 'Microsoft.Web/sites/host@2022-09-01'? I get a warning when using this: Resource type "Microsoft.Web/sites/host@2022-09-01" does not have types available.bicep(BCP081

Comment: Try to use the latest version. resource.listKeys() is just a shortcut for reference really