# How can I get Azure Functions keys from Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-bicep

I have the following code to create an Azure **Function App** with **Bicep** lang

```bash
resource webSite 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'xxxxxx'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: 'zzzzzz'
    siteConfig: {     
      appSettings: [
        // some values
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then I need to get the host keys like 'master' or 'default' key

I tried some options like

```bash
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions@2022-03-01' existing = { name: 'xxxxxx' }

output key string = functionApp.listkeys().properties.masterKey
```

or

```bash
output key string = listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/host', 'xxxxxx', 'default'), '2022-03-01').masterKey
```

But I allways receive an error from Azure with this message `Encountered an error (BadGateway) from host runtime.`

There are a way to get the keys easily?

To get the keys do I need to deploy a function inside my Function App?

Comment: Curiously, the same approach with AZ CLI returns the same result `az functionapp function keys list --function-name myFunctionName --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myFunctionName` returns `Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'` and, from Activity log I read `Encountered an error (BadGateway) from host runtime.`

Comment: You you try that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69254407/4167200 ?

Comment: @Sergio did one of the answers help solve your problem? If so, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

***To get the Azure functionApp/function keys, I tried the below approaches and it worked for me.***

1. ***Using Az CLI:***

Use below command to retrieve the `function app keys and their secret` values in `Azure Bash`:

```bash
az functionapp keys list -g <resourcegroup> -n <functionappname>
```

***Output:***

[image]

Use below command to retrieve the `function keys and their secret` values in `Azure Bash`:

```bash
az functionapp function keys list -g <resourcegroup> -n <functionappname> --function-name <functionname>
```

***Output:***

[image]

2. ***Bicep code:***

*I also tried by creating a bicep configuration file in my environment with the below script as follows:*

```
param  functionApp  string
resource  appKeys  'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions@2022-03-01'  existing ={
name: functionApp
}
output key object = listkeys(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', functionApp), '/host/default/'),'2021-02-01').masterKey
```

*Build succeeded by using below command:*

`bicep build < filename >`:

[image]

**Note:** ***But in bicep, output should not have secret values according to the linter rule code as detailed in*** [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/linter-rule-outputs-should-not-contain-secrets#linter-rule-code).

*Alternatively, you can refer* [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47985475/19785512) *given by @Shui shengbao to list the function keys with ARM json template.*

Answer (score 1):

The error is indicative of a storage account access issue.

Please check your appsettings. You can also see if you can show the keys using Azure Portal.

- `AzureWebJobsStorage` should be a valid connection string and the account accessible (VNETs etc.)
- If `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` is set, make sure your function code is also deployed correctly and working

A valid bicep code to get the keys:

```
output key string = listkeys('${functionApp.id}/host/default', '2022-03-01').masterKey
```

Note that `listkeys('${functionApp.id}/host/xxxx/default' ...` is incorrect. You don't need `xxxx` there. If you need the key of a slot you can use `output key2 string = listkeys('${functionApp.id}/slots/${slotname}/host/default', ...`

Comment: If WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE == 1 do I need to deploy the function App before get the keys?

Comment: @Sergio from what I read it would be advisable to only set this when you are about to deploy the function app. You can get issues getting the keys if did not deploy any content yet but have already set the flag.